# Codeigniter db like not working in array

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sql-like

I want to add more columns to search in my database, this is my original script.

```
public function getProductsByName($name, $limit, $start) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->order_by("id", "desc"); 
    $this->db->like("name", $name); 
    $query = $this->db->get('products');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is my modified script to find in 3 columns like.

```
public function getProductsByName($name, $limit, $start) {
   $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
   $this->db->order_by("id", "desc"); 
   $array = array('name' => $name, 'code' => $code, 'ean' => $ean);
   $this->db->like($array); 
   $query = $this->db->get('products');

   if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        return $data;
   }

   return false;
}
```

What is wrong here?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what you are trying can you explain briefly.............

Comment: Im trying to search in db by code, name and ean, the first function is just for name. Thanks

Comment: If you are trying for 3 items, are you passing those three as arguments...........I don't think so.....

Answer (score 1):

For selecting the data as like you says ,you need to tell exactly the varible that you use `$code and $ean`.
another things is the `data[]` you are created , there is no need to create an array like this.
you will get the same when you call `$query->result();`

```
public function getProductsByName($name, $limit, $start,$code,$ean) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->order_by("id", "desc"); 
    $array = array('name' => $name, 'code' => $code, 'ean' => $ean);
    $this->db->like($array); 
    $query = $this->db->get('products');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }

    return false;
}
```

hope it will help you